# ThreeJS: Converting from screen 2D coordinate to world 3D coordinate on the camera near plane? R73

Tags: three.js

I have got a little bit in trouble with coordinate conversion. 
I have an object on screen with known coordinates (x,y) and I want to convert it to world coordinates (x,y,z) as it would be projected on the camera's near plane.

So far, I can make a projection onto Z plane like this:

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouse.x, mouse.y, 1 );
vector.unproject( camera );
```

But unfortunately I cannot proceed further :(

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you use -1 for the z component, you'll be projected on the near plane, instead the far plane:

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouse.x, mouse.y, -1 ).unproject( camera );
```

Assuming mouse.x and mouse.y are between -1 and 1.

three.js r.73

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly, of course. I got mess with my coordinates in other part of the code. Sure, my mouse is in frustum coordinate range.

Answer (score 4):

I found another answer, do not know if it is right for you.

```js
var getSceneToWorld = function(dx, dy) {
var projector = new THREE.Projector();
var mouse3D = new THREE.Vector3(dx / window.innerWidth * 2 - 1, -dy / window.innerHeight * 2 + 1, 0.5);
projector.unprojectVector(mouse3D, camera);
mouse3D.sub(camera.position);
mouse3D.normalize(); 
var rayCaster = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, mouse3D); var scale = window.innerWidth * 2; 
var rayDir = new THREE.Vector3(rayCaster.ray.direction.x * scale, rayCaster.ray.direction.y * scale, rayCaster.ray.direction.z * scale);
var rayVector = new THREE.Vector3(camera.position.x + rayDir.x, camera.position.y + rayDir.y, camera.position.z + rayDir.z); 
return rayVector; 
}
```

reference material:http://barkofthebyte.azurewebsites.net/post/2014/05/05/three-js-projecting-mouse-clicks-to-a-3d-scene-how-to-do-it-and-how-it-works

Comment: Note that this answer doesn't work anymore, as the threejs API has changed significantly since April 2017.