# How to get the Vector3 of a point from the viewport perspective in three.js?

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I need to create 2 `THREE.Vector3` points. from the browser viewport perspective.

- The starting point is the top right corner of the browser viewport,
  far from the screen
- The ending point is the centre (both horizontal
  centre and verticle centre) of the browser viewport, close to the
  screen.

The problem is, how could I convert the web coordinate to the three.js coordinate so I can start making this cubic bezier curve3?

Google Fu is not working for me this time... what am I missing here? Thanks

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve. Have you seen this example? https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_spline_editor

Comment: Thanks dude, checked, not quite, but i narrowed down the question hope I can solve it one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is `Vector3.unproject()`. This mechanism converts screen-space coordinates in the `[-1, 1]` range, to a 3D position by "unprojecting" it from the camera.

The screen-space coordinates, also known as normalized device coordinates (NDC), are as follows:

```js
x = -1  // left side of the screen
x = 1   // right side of the screen
y = -1  // bottom
y = 1   // top
z = -1  // far plane
z = 1   // near plane
```

So if you want the right-top-far corner to center-center-near, follow the table above:

```js
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(/* ... */);

// Start in NDC space
var cornerVec = new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, -1);
var middleVec = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);

// Convert to 3D space
cornerVec.unproject(camera);
middleVec.unproject(camera);

console.log(cornerVec);
console.log(middleVec);
```

You can read more about [`Vector3.unproject()` in the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.unproject). It's called "unproject" because it does the opposite of ["project"](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.project).

Comment: why is not this explained in the docs? brief, concise and direct way to understand what unproject does and how to operate it. Thanks

Comment: is the near/far 'z' switched in your answer. I think it is the other way round. z=-1 -> near, z=1 -> far. Also according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660063/threejs-converting-from-screen-2d-coordinate-to-world-3d-coordinate-on-the-came)